# Anchor link keeps jumping, no matter what I do

Tags: jquery, html, anchor, page-jump

Ok, this is driving me crazy!

I'm working with a "tab like" submenu to show 3 different tables. Each link inside this submenu hides the current content and show another one.

**NOTE:** for now I'll leave a direct link to the page [I'm working on](http://wp.publishyours.com.br/publishyours/planos-custos) so you may check the problem by yourself.

To avoid the `<a>` (anchor) jumps, I'm already trying `<a onclick="return false;">` (which works fine in another site I have). In my jQuery code I'm also using "e.preventDefault();" that helps avoiding the jump to the top of the page, but even using it the page always jumps to some part of the page above the sublinks.

I really don't know what else I could do to avoid this jumps.

For now this is what I have inside my html:

```
<nav id="submenu" class="menu">
<ul>
    <li class="current-menu-item"><a onclick="return false;" href="#" rel="statics">Sites Estáticos</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="return false;" href="#" rel="dynamics">Sites Dinâmicos</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="return false;" href="#" rel="extras">Serviços Extras</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
function subSections(){
$('nav.menu li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //this helps, but don't solve the problem
    var active = $(this).parent();
    var currSection = $(this).attr('rel');
    if(active.hasClass('current-menu-item')!=true){
        // Add and remove 'current-menu-item' class
        $('nav.menu .current-menu-item').removeClass('current-menu-item');
        active.addClass('current-menu-item');
        // Hide currentSection and Show the clicked one
        $('.showing').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#'+currSection).fadeIn('slow').addClass('showing');
        }).removeClass('showing');
    }
});
```

}

Also, maybe there's a better way to do this "show and hide" stuff, but this seems to work fine. Well, I'll be glad if anyone can shed a light on this problem and help me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Notice it is not really jumping anywhere. You are altering the height of the page, so it's natural for it to reposition the viewport if the page is made smaller

Comment: Alexander, thanks for your fast answer. Well, I understand that I'm changing the height of the page. If I use a min-height that's at least the height of the bigger content, the problem is kinda solved (I already checked that), but there must be a way to avoid this jump, doesn't it?

It could even jump to the top of the submenu, but not much above it, as it's doing =\

Comment: Instead of `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` have you tried just using `show()` and `hide()`?

Comment: Jason, great! That solves the jumping problem! Strange thing is that my animation is gone. Anyway I can use show() and hide() and still keep the animation? Anyway, that's already a good answer to my problem! =]

Comment: @7th Awesome! I'll write it up as an official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) instead of `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`.

If you want to keep the animation, you can try `.show('slow')` and `.hide('slow')` but that may trigger the jumping problem also.

Comment: Yep, when animation happens, the jump is triggered again =(
But hey, it's working! Thanks Jason ;)

Comment: @7th, I'm glad it's working for you and thanks for marking this as the accepted answer. Would it be too much trouble to ask for an upvote as well? :)

Answer (score 1):

Also, just to refactor the code a small bit and save a bit of typing (and make the script more dynamic) you don't need to write `onclick="return false;"`on every html link. Simply place return false at the end of the .click function in jQuery.

```
function subSections(){
$('nav.menu li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //this helps, but don't solve the problem
    var active = $(this).parent();
    var currSection = $(this).attr('rel');
    if(active.hasClass('current-menu-item')!=true){
        // Add and remove 'current-menu-item' class
        $('nav.menu .current-menu-item').removeClass('current-menu-item');
        active.addClass('current-menu-item');
        // Hide currentSection and Show the clicked one
        $('.showing').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#'+currSection).fadeIn('slow').addClass('showing');
        }).removeClass('showing');

    // Return false for all links in the nav onclick
    return false;

    }
});
```